# Wie werden die Wörter »leider« und »unglücklicherweise« verwendet?

Tags: preposition, meaning-in-context

Ich weiß nicht, wie die Wörter *»leider«* und *»unglücklicherweise«* benutzt werden. Können Sie das bitte mit Beispielen erklären?

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen *»unglücklicherweise«* und *»unglücklicher«*?

Comment: Ungefähr so wie z.B. die Wörter *hélas* und *malheureusement* in Französisch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die Worte *leider* und *unglücklicherweise* sind keine Präpositionen, sondern **Adverbien**. Adverbien beschreiben meist den Satz als ganzes genauer.

> Es ist für eine Entschuldigung **leider** zu spät.
>
> Die Bahn ist am Sonntag **leider** nicht gefahren.

Wo ein solches Adverb in den Satz eingefügt wird, hängt davon ab, was man betonen will. Ein Adverb betont den folgenden Satzteil. Ganz vorne ist es selbst zusätzlich noch besonders betont.

> **Leider** ist es für eine Entschuldigung zu spät.
>
> Es ist **leider** für eine Entschuldigung zu spät.
>
> **Leider** ist die Bahn am Sonntag nicht gefahren.
>
> Die Bahn ist **leider** am Sonntag nicht gefahren.

In manchen einfachen Sätzen darf man Adverbien ganz ans Ende setzen:

> Dann verließ ihn der Mut **leider**.

---

Und ja, es gibt einen Unterschied zwischen dem Adverb *unglücklicherweise* und dem Adjektiv *unglücklich*, im Komparativ *unglücklicher*.

Das normale Adverb beschreibt die Umstände und entspricht im Deutschen der Grundform des Adjektivs.

> Die unglückliche Frau war unglücklich.

Man kann aus dem Komperativ und dem Superlativ jeweils ein eigenes Adverb bilden:

> Die unglückliche Frau war unglücklicher.
>
> Die unglückliche Frau war am unglücklichsten.

Man kann mit -erweise aus einem Adjektiv ein weiteres Adverb bilden:

> Die unglückliche Frau war unglücklicherweise unglücklicher (als zuvor).

Dieses -erweise–Adverb wertet die Umstände aus Sicht des Sprechers.

Und auch hier gibt es wieder Adverbien aus Komparativ und Superlativ:

> Noch unglücklicher**er**weise geht das.
>
> Glücklichsterweise macht das aber niemand.

Comment: Hmmm... Ein Satz wie "Die unglückliche Frau war unglücklicherweise unglücklicher (als zuvor)." ist m.E. eher verwirrend als erhellend, wenn man den Unterschied noch nicht so richtig kennt.

Answer (score 2):

Ich würde den ersten Teil der Antwort von Janka dahingehend präzisieren, dass es sich hier in beiden Fällen um eine Unterart von Adverbien handelt, nämlich um solche, die, wie Janka richtig schrieb, sich auf den ganzen Satz beziehen. In der Duden-Grammatik heißen sie 'Satzadverbien' bzw. 'Kommentaradverbien' oder auch 'Modalwörter'. Anders als die Sorte von Adverbien, die einem als erstes beim Stichwort 'Adverb' einfällt (heute, hier, flugs...), beschreiben oder präzisieren oder situieren 'leider' und 'unglücklicherweise' nicht den wiedergegebenen Sachverhalt, sondern verdeutlichen die Position des Sprechers gegenüber dem Sachverhalt als 'der Sprecher bedauert, dass...'.

Mit 'unglücklicherweise' wird, anders als mit 'leider', präzisiert, dass ein negativ erlebtes Geschehen auf dem unglücklichen Zusammentreffen zweier für sich genommen relativ 'normaler' Ereignisse beruht, also zur Charakterisierung einer negativen Koinzidenz: 'Ihre Mutter hatte noch versucht, sie zu erreichen, aber unglücklicherweise hatte Claudi an diesem Tag ihr Handy zu Hause vergessen.' Beim Lesen eines solchen Satzes vermutet man, dass sich aus diesem unseligen Umstand sehr unerfreuliche, vielleicht sogar fatale Konsequenzen ergeben könnten. Demgegenüber bezeichnet 'leider' lediglich ein Bedauern über den ungünstigen Ablauf.

Beispiele:

*ich muss jetzt gehen* - hier kann leider jede Position einnehmen:

- leider muss ich jetzt gehen
- ich muss jetzt leider gehen
- ich muss jetzt gehen, leider
- *ich muss leider jetzt gehen* = nicht ganz so akzeptabel wie die anderen Sätze, die Bedeutung nähert sich einem 'leider jetzt schon' an.

Statt dieser Sätze könnte man auch in etwa gleichbedeutend auch sagen:

- Schade, ich muss jetzt gehen; oder:
- So leid es mir tut, aber ich muss jetzt gehen.

In diesen Sätzen würde 'unglücklicherweise nicht gut passen. Beispiel für 'unglücklicherweise':

- Unglücklicherweise fiel am Tag seiner Abreise der Zug aus, der ihn
  zum Flugplatz bringen sollte, so dass er seinen Flug beinahe verpasst
  hätte, wenn der Sohn des mitleidigen Hotelchefs ihn nicht zum
  Flughafen gefahren hätte.

Für mich klingt in vielen Sätzen mit 'unglücklicherweise' ein 'ausgerechnet' an. Man könnte dafür oft auch sagen 'zu dumm, dass' oder einen Kommentar abgeben wie 'was für ein dummer Zufall!', wobei 'dumm' hier in der Bedeutung 'ärgerlich' zu verstehen ist.

Satzadverbien mit '...erweise' sind ein produktives Wortbildungsinstrument. Aus fast allen Adjektiven, die man in die Schablone 'ich finde es ..., dass' einsetzen könnte, lassen sich zu solchen Adverbien umformen:

http://corpora.uni-leipzig.de/de/res?corpusId=deu_newscrawl_2011&word=*erweise

(Hier immer auf 'mehr' am Ende der Liste klicken, dann kommen endlos viele.)

Es gibt eine zweite Gruppe solcher Satzadverbien, die keine Bewertung durch den Sprecher markieren sondern den Grad an Wahrscheinlichkeit bestimmen, mit dem das Eintreten eines Ereignisses oder die Tatsächlichkeit eines Sachverhalts relativiert werden kann: *vielleicht, bestimmt, gewiss, kaum (noch)* ... Das erinnert an 'Modallogik', insofern ist hier die Bezeichnung 'Modalwort' passend. Die Duden-Grammatik nennt diese Gruppe 'epistemische Adverbien'. Man kann eine Aussage wie 'vielleicht kommt er noch' auch formulieren als 'es kann sein, dass er noch kommt', um den modalen Aspekt von 'vielleicht' mit einem Modalverb zu verdeutlichen.

Was die zweite Frage angeht (den Unterschied zwischen 'unglücklicher' und 'unglücklicherweise':

'Unglücklicher' ist entweder Komparativ oder eine deklinierte Form zum Adjektiv 'unglücklich'. Es lässt sich klassisch adverbial verwenden, wie die meisten Adjektive:

- Die Sache ist noch unglücklicher gelaufen als beim letzten Mal.
- Eine unglücklicher Verliebte als Carla mag man sich gar nicht vorstellen.

Beispiele für adjektivische Verwendung wären

- komparativisch prädikativ: Wer ist in dieser Beziehung unglücklicher, sie oder er?
- attributiv maskulin: Ein unglücklicher Zufall wollte, dass, kaum hatte er den entscheidenden Satz 'wir stehen fest an Ihrer Seite' ausgesprochen, der Stuhl unter ihm zusammenkrachte und er sich auf dem Boden umgeben von lauter Kleinholz wiederfand.

Ein nicht-komparativisches 'unglücklicher' kann darüber hinaus Dativ und Genitiv femininum Singular sowie Genitiv Plural sein. Die Wortbildung 'unglücklicherweise' erklärt sich aus einem (adverbialen) Genitiv femininum; es wurde früher und wird teilweise noch heute getrennt geschrieben: "Unglücklicher Weise aber wurde dieser edelmüthige und eifrige Greis selbst ein Opfer des Todes für vierzehn junge Personen, die er bereits gerettet hatte." (Anders Sparrmann, Reise nach dem Vorgebirge ..., 1784).

Solche adverbialen Genitive begegnen einem noch heute in manchmal altertümlich anmutenden Wendungen wie 'stehenden Fußes' (= sofort) oder 'schnellen Schrittes'; manchmal sind sie auch heute noch verbreitet: 'eines schönen Tages'.

Comment: +1 für die Erläuterung.